# iTextSharp apply font style to existing font

Tags: c#, itext, font-style

In the beginning of a document I created a new font:

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var font1 = new Font(baseFont, 12, Font.NORMAL);
```

Somewhere in the middle of the same document I want to use the same font (fontfamily & size) with different style: bold & italic.

Can I somehow change the style of **font1** or do I have to create a new Font?

Note: I know I can do:

```
font1.SetStyle("bold");
font1.SetStyle("italic");
```

but how about both? And maybe also **underline**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in

```
BaseFont baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibri.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

you load the font file for regular Calibri. If you derive any `Font` from this `BaseFont`, it uses the regular Calibri font file, no matter which style attributes you set. This in particular means that

- a "bold" style is implemented by not only filling the normal glyph contour but also stroking a line along it (a variant of what's called "poor man's bold") and
- an "italic" style is implemented by applying a transformation matrix which skews a bit.

You get better quality bold and italic variations by loading the bold or italic Calibri

```
BaseFont baseFontBold = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibrib.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
BaseFont baseFontItalic = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibrii.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
BaseFont baseFontBoldItalic = BaseFont.CreateFont(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\Calibriz.ttf", "Identity-H", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

and deriving a `Font` with style "normal" from the matching `BaseFont`.

---

That been said, now to your main question:

> I know I can do:
>
> ```
> font1.SetStyle("bold");
> font1.SetStyle("italic");
> ```
>
> but how about both? And maybe also underline...

For *both* you can simply do as you wrote

```
font1.SetStyle("bold");
font1.SetStyle("italic");
```

i.e. setting both sequentially, because `SetStyle(String)` actually works more like an `AddStyle`. Alternatively, though, you can also do

```
font1.SetStyle("bold italic");
```

If you need to reset the set of selected styles to normal, you can use `SetStyle(int)` which really works like a setter should:

```
font1.SetStyle(0);
```

> And maybe also underline...

The `String` constants for the available styles are

- "normal"
- "bold"
- "italic"
- "oblique"
- "underline"
- "line-through"